# How to use conditional expectation to find another expectation

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

I have $E[X|Y] = Y + \frac12$, and $E[Y] = \frac12$.

How can I use these two facts to demonstrate that $E[XY] = \frac34$?

I tried multiplying $E[X|Y]$ by $E[Y]$, but that didn't really get me anywhere...

Comment: No information about $E[Y^2]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the tower rule and the fact that $E[YX\mid Y]=YE[X\mid Y]$:

$$\begin{align}E[XY] &= E[E[XY\mid Y]] \\[1ex] &= E[Y\,E[X\mid Y]] \\[1ex] &= E\left[Y\left(Y+\tfrac12\right)\right] \\[1ex] &= E\left[Y^2\right]+\tfrac12E[Y]\\[1ex] &= E\left[Y^2\right]+\tfrac14\end{align}$$

*If* $E\left[Y^2\right]=\tfrac12$ then, indeed, $E[XY]=\tfrac34.$